# HTTP POST response in JSON array how to retrieve in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, http

An HTTP POST response is getting the string [[10000,"TRANS"]].

How can I retrieve this into separate values, 10000 as number and "TRANS" as string, in 2 variables in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

[[]] doesn't look like proper JSON, but anyway...

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' for reading of JSON (+add the reference to System.Web.Extensions library)
Dim JSONDictionary = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON)
```

Then extract what you want. Inspect JSONDictionary with breakpoint.